# JavaScript開発におけるJavaライクな名前空間の管理ができる方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript

下記に合致するNamespace管理がきるJavascriptのライブラリ／スーパーセットは存在するでしょうか？

- 「Jav‌​aライクな名前空間」－　com.hogehoge.foo.bar のような名前空間が持てるかどうか
- Knockout.js と連携して名前空間を管理することができる
- 開発規模は約5人くらいのチーム
- Jsのファイル数は30ファイル程度

Comment: 求めるものの条件が少しはっきりしていないため、後から読む人が参考にしにくく、今ついている回答の方も求めている条件にマッチしているのかがはっきりしません。「Javaライクな名前空間」「Viewを助けてくれるフレームワークとの親和性」「複数人（5人くらい）で使う上で最適」という条件を具体化していただくことはできるでしょうか。

Comment: 伝わりにくく、大変申し訳ありません。修正内容確認頂けますでしょうか？

Comment: 何人もの方に大変ご迷惑おかけして大変申し訳ございません。修正いたしました。ご確認頂けますでしょうか？

Comment: @digdagdag 修正ありがとうございます。再オープンしたしました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TypeScript`に`module`というnamespaceに似た仕組みがあるので、それを利用してみました。

```
module com.mokelab {
    export function work() {
        console.log("Androidアプリ書いてます");
    }
}
// namespace付きで呼び出し
com.mokelab.work();
```

このTypeScriptのコードは、次のJavaScriptにコンパイルされました。このような形でnamespaceを実現するのも手かもしれません。

```
var com;
(function (com) {
    var mokelab;
    (function (mokelab) {
        function work() {
            console.log("Androidアプリ書いてます");
        }
        mokelab.work = work;
    })(mokelab = com.mokelab || (com.mokelab = {}));
})(com || (com = {}));
// namespace付きで呼び出し
com.mokelab.work();
```

Comment: なるほど。TypeScriptを使うのは一つの手ですね。ありがとうございます。TypeScript調査してみたいと思います。